# Which version of SQL Server supports.Net framework 4.5?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2012, .net-framework-version

I am new to .NET technology and I am using Visual Studio 2012 and .net framework 4.5. I tried SQL Server 2008 but I'm unable to connect to it with server name `.` and `.\SQLEXPRESS`.

Which version of SQL Server should I install for database access and please provide the link for same?

Comment: I found that if you only have 1 instance of SQL server installed / running then you don't need to use the instance name. Eg, instead of entering: MY-COMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS just enter MY-COMPUTER\ - this worked for me using SQL Server 2014 and Visual Studio Professional 2013

Comment: .NET supports any version of SQL Server from at least version 2000 onwards..... it depends on which **edition** you installed, and what **instance name** you picked for the server when you installed it.

Comment: @BnMcG just to clarify a confusion, its not only one instance, Its actually If you are trying to connect to the `Default Instance` then you can only use the machine name to connect to it. Regardless of how many instances you have on your machine. But if you have only once instance and it is a named instance you will need to use full `MachineName\InstanceName`.

Comment: Can you post the connecting string you are using to connect to sql server ?

Comment: @M.Ali My bad! That is correct. If you have only one instance is it not automatically set to the default?

Comment: @BnMcG No default instance will have the name Microsoft gives by default I think it is `MSSQLSERVER` in most cases except Express Edition where it is `SQLEXPRESS` I think. If you pick any other name other than these default names provided by Microsoft it will be a named instance and vice versa. You can have only one default instance on a machine and many named instances.

Comment: This question is worded wrong and should be closed.  It reads like its asking for which Version of SQL Server supports Connections from .net 4.5, when the Questioner is actually just someone who doesn't know how to connect to their SQL Database from their .net code.  All .net Versions can connect to all SQL Server Versions - it's not a matter of which supports which.

Answer (score 2):

VS.NET 2012 ships with SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDb. If you use LocalDb and its file is located in App_Data\DatabaseFileName.mdf then you could connect using

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFileName.mdf;InitialCatalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True" />
```

To see what database is in use you can either from VS.NET or using SQL Server Management Studio

[image: VS.NET]

If you use other database, e.g. SQL Server 2008, you need to make sure that

- name of the server and the SQL Server instance
- server is up and running

You can use ".", "(local)", or "localhost" in place of the server name to specify the local computer, but you need to make sure that server is there.

Open SQL Server Management Studio, Connect to Server and see the name of the server and its authentication type. If it is a Windows Authentication you can use Integrated Security=True in the connection string.

Example:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   string connectionString = @"Data Source=\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBNAME_HERE;Integrated Security=True";

   using (SqlConnection objSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
   {
    try {
        objSqlConnection.Open();
        objSqlConnection.Close();
        Response.Write("Connection is successfull");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Response.Write("Error : " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

}

Reed more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/SQLEXPCTAV2/enus/default.aspx) have the following limitations:

- Maximum database size 10GB
- Maximum usage of Ram 1GB
- Single physical CPU
- No SQL Server Agent (job scheduler)
- Profiler tool is not included

Also, your connection string should be something like this:

> Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFolder\MyDataFile.mdf;Database=dbname;
>   Trusted_Connection=Yes;